# Select rows from Data.table programmatically based on column criteria

Tags: r, data.table

I have a question on the way to select programmatically the rows from a `data.table` based on values from columns.

Let say I have below Data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
```

Now I want to select rows where `y = 3 and v = 2`

Normally I can use below code

```
> DT[y==3& v==2]
   x y v
1: a 3 2
```

But in my case, such selection criteria is itself a variable, and put in a different `DF`

```
> DF = data.frame('1' = c('y', 'v'), '2' = c(3,2)); DF
  X1 X2
1  y  3
2  v  2
```

In this case, the value of `X2` above will change, even number of rows is also variable (i.e. assuming I have a bigger `DT` with more columns, some additional rows in `DF` might come based on the generation criteria of `DF`)

Is there any way to **use `DF` to select rows in `DT` programmatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to `eval` by `paste`ing the columns of 'DF' to create an expression

```
DT[eval(parse(text= paste(DF$X1, DF$X2,  sep="==", collapse=" & ")))]
#   x y v
#1: a 3 2
```

---

or we can specify the `.SDcols` as the 'X1' column, then compare the `.SD` with 'X2' and `Reduce` it to a logical `vector` with `&`, subset the rows

```
DT[DT[, Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, .SD, DF$X2)),.SDcols = as.character(DF$X1)]]
#   x y v
#1: a 3 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `join`:

```
DT[structure(as.list(DF$X2), names=DF$X1), on=as.character(DF$X1)]
```

Comment: brilliant but need to convert `X1` to character first. `setNames(as.list(DF$X2), DF$X1)` would be possible instead of `structure(as.list(DF$X2), names=DF$X1)`

Comment: oh i think i always have `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`