# Conditionally test a data.table filter

Tags: r, data.table

I feel like there has to be a neater solution that the horrendous code I am about to post.

```
library(data.table)
mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
findMpg <- function(data) {
  mpg <- data[cyl == 6 & hp > 180, mpg]
  if (length(mpg) == 0L) {
    mpg <- data[cyl == 8 & hp > 300, mpg]
    if (length(mpg) == 0L) {
      return(NA_real_)
    } else {
      return(mpg)
    }
  } else {
    return(mpg)
  }
}
findMpg(mtcars)
```

Essentially I want to be able to check (maybe in the filter, maybe a join?) if the first filter fails then try the next filter, if that fails then try the next, etc.

Comment: Is it just two values (6 and 8)? Or all possible values for that variable?

Comment: I'd like a generic solution. In my real world problem I have 4 tests. So do filter A, if it "fails" (i.e. returns no result), do filter B, if it returns no result do filter C, if it returns no result do filter D, if that returns no result then return `NA`. It's horrendous code and I feel like I should be able to simplify it.

Comment: what are your re-world conditions

Comment: They are similar to what I have given examples of. If a couple of columns meet a certain condition, great, if not check other column conditions.

Comment: *"neater solution"*, perhaps. *"Shorter solution"* (aka code-golf), almost certainly. But *"clearer solution"*, I think less likely.

Comment: I think you could be right @r2evans

Answer (score 3):

A variant of @Aziz's loop approach:

```
find = function(..., x = data.table(mtcars), j = quote(mpg), default = NA_real_){
  is = substitute(list(...))[-1]
  for (ii in seq_along(is)){
    i = is[[ii]]
    res = x[eval(i), eval(j)]
    if (length(res) > 0L) return(res)
  }
  return(default)
}

find(cyl == 6 & hp > 180, cyl == 8 & hp > 300)
# [1] 15
```

As @r2evans points out, for piping with magrittr, it will be more convenient to write it with data as the first argument:

```
find = function(x = data.table(mtcars), ..., j = quote(mpg), default = NA_real_){
  ...
}

data %>% find(cyl == 6 & hp > 180, cyl == 8 & hp > 300)
```

Comment: This seems analogous to a "coalesce"-like function, in that it will use the first expression that returns something. Nice touch. You might consider making the data the first argument, so that it can be used in `%>%` pipes. (Well, it can always be used, with `... %>% find(cond1, cond2, x = .)`, but some prefer not needing to use the `.` placeholder.)

Comment: Frank2, did you intend to shift the `x=` argument to the left of the `...`? Your second declaration is unchanged from the first :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a dupe of [Select rows from Data.table programmatically based on column criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56833293), but here's the code:

```r
library(data.table)
mt <- mtcars
setDT(mt)

conditions <- list(
  "cyl == 6 & hp > 180",
  "cyl == 8 & hp > 180"
)
for (cond in conditions) {
  out <- mt[eval(parse(text = cond)), mpg]
  if (length(out)) break
}
out
# [1] 14.3 10.4 10.4 14.7 13.3 15.8 15.0
cond
# [1] "cyl == 8 & hp > 180"
```

I should note that you control your own fate here ... if there is any user-determination of the list of conditions, you open the code up to code-injection attacks, R's version of ["Little Bobby Tables"](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop to check each value in a vector, and return the first one that is non-zero.

```
library(data.table)
mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
findMpg <- function(data) {

  cylList = c(6,8)

  # Or you can use this for all possible cyl values
  #cylList = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))

  for (c in cylList) {
    mpg = data[cyl == c & hp > 300, mpg]
    if (length(mpg) > 0L)
      return(mpg)
  }

  # if all fail, return NA
  return (NA_real_)
}
print(findMpg(mtcars))
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think my example is representative enough of my real world problem. In that problem each filter is different. I'll update my question to be more representative,

Comment: I updated the example. I _could_ use a loop and some kind of `parse(eval(text = 'filter_here'))` but that feels very messy.

Comment: Oh I see. So you have a set of criteria that you go through (each has conditions on multiple variables) and find the first that has non-zero result?

Comment: Exactly that, yes :)