# R data.table: select rows based on variables whose names are stored elsewhere

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following:

```
library(data.table)

DataTableA <- data.table(v1 = c(1, 2, NA, 6, 3, NA),
                         v2 = c(NA, 4, NA, NA, 1, 2),
                         v3 = c(3, 3, NA, 4, 2, NA),
                         v4 = c(2, NA, 3, NA, 3, NA),
                         v5 = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4))

DataTableA

##    v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
## 1:  1 NA  3  2  1
## 2:  2  4  3 NA NA
## 3: NA NA NA  3 NA
## 4:  6 NA  4 NA NA
## 5:  3  1  2  3  3
## 6: NA  2 NA NA  4

varnames <- c("v2", "v4", "v5")
```

What is the best way of getting the rows of `DataTableA` where at least one of the variables named in `varnames` is not NA, without explicitly referring to the variable names?

I know I could do

```
DataTableA[!is.na(v2) | !is.na(v4) | !is.na(v5)]
```

but I want to avoid writing out the variable names.

Something that works is

```
DataTableA[apply(!is.na(DataTableA[, ..varnames]), 1, any)]
```

but I'm wondering if there's a better way. If there's not, that's OK of course. I don't have any problem with using `apply` as above, but what I've seen of data.table so far makes me think there might be a simpler approach.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833293/select-rows-from-data-table-programmatically-based-on-column-criteria) is similar, but more complex.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use specify the 'varnames' in `.SDcols`, loop over the `.SD` (Subset of Data.table), apply the function and `Reduce`

```
DataTableA[DataTableA[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, is.na)), .SDcols = varnames]]
```

---

Or with `rowSums`

```
DataTableA[DataTableA[, rowSums(!is.na(.SD)) > 0, .SDcols = varnames]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer akrun. I don't see those as being simpler than using `apply` as in my question, but as a new data.table user it's useful for me to see more examples using `.SD`.

Comment: `rowSums` will be significantly faster for large data.

Comment: @IanCampbell Thanks, I hadn't considered the speed.

Comment: @mark999 Yes, `apply` is more easier to understand, but looping over rows is less efficient in R compared to columns. In the first solution, loop over the columns and Reduce it.  It should be faster than the apply.  In addition, `apply` would create a `matrix` and this would have some performance issues along with changing the colums types in case if the columns are differen types

Comment: @mark999.  Also, if you want only a base R solution with apply, then converting to `data.table` makes not much sense to me because the peformance improviement with dat.atable would be much higher when working on big datasets

Comment: @akrun Thanks. I didn't just want a base R solution.

Comment: @mark999 in your example and code, the `apply` also works, but i am saying with a general case.  It would give you some unexpected bugs

Comment: I might just mention that the thinking behind my question was that because data.table allows, for example, `DataTableA[!is.na(v1)]` instead of `DataTableA[!is.na(DataTable$v1)]`, there might be a way of doing it with `varnames` but without having to write `DataTableA` again inside the `[ ]`. But it looks like there isn't, which is fine.

Comment: @mark999 The `.SDcols` is one and if there is only column, u can also use `get` or `eval(as.name`